# Comparing datetime values in different ways

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

OK, I thought I was pretty good with SQL...I have to do a comparison between two datetime columns.

Could someone explain the difference between

```
DateA > DateB
```

and

```
DateDiff(d,DateB,DateA) >= 1
```

I thought these two statements were functionally equivalent, but I guess I was wrong...

Comment: Did you try them to compare the differences?

Comment: One big difference is that the first is [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and the second is not. Don't use the second expression in a where clause. If you need the functionality from the second expression you should rewrite your first query something like this `cast(DateA as date) > cast(DateB as date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateA > DateB
```

checks if DateA is bigger than DateB (01/12/2012 14:50:01 is bigger than 01/12/2012 14:50:00).

---

```
DateDiff(d,DateB,DateA) >= 1
```

checks if the difference in days (datepart `d` as first argument) is equal or bigger than 1 day.

Answer (score 2):

`DateA > DateB` will evaluate true if DateA is at least one millisecond bigger than DateB

`DateDiff(d,DateB,DateA) >= 1` will evaluate true if the difference between DateB and DateA is at least one day

In other words, if you think that today at 12:00 is bigger than today at 11:00 go with option one

If you think that a date is bigger than another just after midnight, go with option two

Comment: `is bigger than one day` - I think you meant `is at least one day`

Comment: it seems the same to me, one day or more. But thanks for the correction :)

Comment: `bigger than one day` is `> 1` not `>= 1`

Comment: oh got it. I should have said bigger or equal than one day. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`DateA` is greater than `DateB` if it is one minute or one second or one millisecond later.

Your `DateDiff` is looking for a difference of one whole day.

Whether you intend it or not, `DateTime` always contains a time, so you have to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

`DateA > DateB` will be true if `DateA` is even *fractionally* larger than `DateB` (say 1 millisecond).

`DateDiff(d,DateB,DateA) >= 1` will be true if the difference between the date is a day or more.